# NHibernate multiple column mapping collection

Tags: nhibernate

I have this situation:

I have several tables table_1, table_2... table_n, they belong to different data but they have some fields in common, record_id, form_id where id is the primary key. All these tables are represented by a single class Record (Id, Form, Attributes)

I have another table tbl_attachments which have attachment_id, record_id, form_id (record_id is not enough because the record_id can be repeated over table_X tables.

The problem I have is I want to have property Attachments in class Record, to get the records attachments from tbl_attachments if any.

Can you help me with the mapping on nhibernate to get this done?

I appreciate any help.

Edit: Forgot to say that a Record on table_X can have multiple attachments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this using AnyMapping

```
abstract class RecordBase
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual int FormId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}

class RecordA : RecordBase
{ }

class Attachment
{
    public virtual int id { get; set; }

    public virtual RecordBase Record { get; set; }
}

class RecordAMap : ClassMap<RecordA>
{
    public RecordAMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Attachments)
            .Where("Form_Id = 5");
    }
}

class AttachmentMap : ClassMap<Attachment>
{
    public AttachmentMap()
    {
        ReferencesAny(x => x.Record)
            .EntityIdentifierColumn("record_id")
            .EntityTypeColumn("form_id")
            .IdentityType<int>()
            .AddMetaValue<RecordA>("5");
    }
}
```

UPDATE: xml mappings

```
<bag where="form_id=5">
  <key column="record_id"/>
  <one-to-many class="Attachment1"/>
</bag>

<any name="Item" id-type="System.Int32" meta-type="System.Int32">
  <column name="form_id" />
  <column name="record_id" />
</any>
```

Comment: Firo, thanks for the quick response, I am using hbm xml files, would you let me know how to map the HasMany(x => x.Attachments)
            .Where("Form_Id = 5"); on an hbm file?